# Google maps authentication not working, Content Security Policy directive

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Ruby on Rails application. After checking it today I saw that my google maps scripts stopped working...When I looked at the console a lot of errors started showing app

I am working on a local machine and but the problem is on the deployed app aswell.
Everything worked fine 2-3 days ago

Rolling back to older versions with git does not help.

I found [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) is it relevant?

Errors in console

> [Report Only] Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because
>   'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "script-src https://* 'self'".
>
> [Report Only] Refused to execute inline script because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src https://*
>   'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or
>   a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
>
> [Report Only] Refused to load the script
>   'http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/15/18/%7Bcommon,util,stats%7D.js'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "script-src https://* 'self'".
>
> [Report Only] Refused to load the script
>   'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1…%2Fstore%2Fentertainment_categories&5e1&callback=*xdc*._dxjdl0&token=95186'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "script-src https://* 'self'".

Comment: have you found a solution to this? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: Yes I was using gem 'secure_headers' and was not following the security prerequisites so it was blocking Google Maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using gem 'secure_headers' and was not following the security prerequisites so it was blocking Google Maps.

Removing [secure_headers](https://github.com/twitter/secureheaders) solved the problem.

You might be blocking Google Maps with other security libs.